# wkhtmltopdf with pdfkit not working on VPS server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I've installed wkhtmltopdf and xvfb. It's working fine in server with command line as well as in django/python shell but with uwsgi+nginx it throwing the below error

```
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 127. error:
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: 25: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: awk: not found
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: 97: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: getopt: not found

Django Version: 1.11.6
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 127. error:
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: 25: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: awk: not found
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: 97: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: getopt: not found
Exception Location: /home/dev/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py in to_pdf, line 159
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

in terminal

```
which awk
/usr/bin/awk
which getopt
/usr/bin/getopt
```

Thanks.